# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI (When creating new Controllers)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a new controller to the Web API that is used to communicate to the client devices.

But any new controllers that i add when navigated to return this error. This must of worked in the past and I am only adding an already working system. Any help would be great.

```
<Error> <Message> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/recentbookin'. </Message> <MessageDetail> No type was found that matches the controller named 'recentbookin'. </MessageDetail> </Error>
```

All the original controllers still work like this one.

```
public class CheckController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is called (in testing) to determine which environments the libraries are running in
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("The current A environment is: " + stores_desktop_library.DatabaseStructure.PTGLIB);
        list.Add("The current C environment is: " + stores_desktop_library.DatabaseStructure.PTGTCDTA);
        return list;
    }
}
```

But the new one I have created does not

```
public class AdvancedLocationController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/AdvancedLocation
    public string Get()
    {
        return "This API is online";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list of database items from a given list of locations
    /// </summary>
    public List<DatabaseItem> Post([FromBody]List<string> locations)
    {
        return dbconnect.GetAdvancedItemsByLocation(locations);            
    }
}
```

The routing config is below.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The URL that I am using is 
    http://localhost/api/check (This is the working one)
    http://localhost/api/AdvancedLocation (This one is not working)

Comment: You need to remove Controller from your uri :  http://localhost/api/AdvancedLocation

Comment: Sorry that was a typo and it is not working with or without

Comment: Where in your codebase are you using the term 'recentbookin' ? That would be the first place to look to troubleshoot if that error is coming for every new call.

Comment: did you try using Route Attribute?

Comment: Search your project for recentbookin, Maybe that term should be replaced by AdvancedLocation

Comment: @AkshayBheda recentbookin is another controller that i am also looking to create both are giving the same error. sorry i did not make that very clear.